# React - App custom route not working in release mode

Tags: reactjs

Updated -

I have added below code in app.js, which works fine in development mode, however does not work in the release or production mode.

```
app.get('/v1redirect', function (req, res) {
    alert("hello");
    // Some redirection code
});
```

We have this generic route in same file at bottom.

```
  app.get(/.*\/[-a-zA-Z0-9]*$/, function(req, res) {
    console.log(`Resolving path: ${req.originalUrl}`);
 });
```

Is wondering deployed environment will change order and invoke generic one?

Can we exclude specific one (/v1redirect) from generic route to make both work.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I 100% guarantee you, it's nothing to do with your code if this is the only code you have.

Comment: Thank you!, should i check something in app.js file then? issue i am facing is i could not put break point as well